# How to correctly display UTF8 characters in Android?

Tags: java, android, utf-8

I have a txt file in UTF8 format:

> æ β ç ð ə ħ ŋ ø θ œ χ n d ŋ b a t d s t b a t d t d t d t ẽ u e ë l n e e m n l e β e e e ĕ e é ē è ȅ

I need to show it in Android, but some symbols do not display correctly.

How can I show all symbols correctly?

Answer (score 0):

It all boils down that you need to read, treat and display it as UTF-8 all the way. For the reading part, you can use [`InputStreamReader`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html) to read an arbitrary [`InputStream`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html) using a specific encoding.

```
reader = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("/file.txt"), "UTF-8");
```

For the treatment part, the Java language should do it transparently without any problems since it perfectly understands Unicode. For the displaying part, that depends on how/where exactly you're displaying it. At least, it should be configured to use UTF-8 for that.

Answer (score 0):

I use UTF8. Its not help. 
I decide this q. 
I connect fonts(ttf) with transcription symbol, and all work correct.